Papaparse csv broken parsing
I'm parsing a csv but during the loop the field is messed up after 539 rows. I think it could be some " character because some times they don't come in pairs due to errors in the source file.
I tried removing fast mode and specify the delimiter but without success:
const result = await fetch(Customers, {
 headers: { "content-type": "text/csv;charset=UTF-8" },
});
const fileContent = await result.text();
let parsedCsvCstomers = Papa.parse(fileContent, {delimiter:"|", header: true, fastMode: false, skipEmptyLines: true})




sometimes they don't come in pairs due to errors in the source file = raise the concern. Can you detail those errors in the source file?

@MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Yes the source file does not have them always in pairs. It's a source defect but I'd need it to be reflected after parsing.
